# How do I configure DHCP bridge with netplan for KVM on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, netplan, virt-manager

I recently installed KVM on Ubuntu 18.04 with requisite tools like virt-manager, libvirt, and qemu.

My problem is that the VMs I spin up are not connected to internet. Some give me an error message saying that my machine is not using DHCP, while other distributions just do not connect at all.

I set it up with the following article:
https://linuxconfig.org/install-and-set-up-kvm-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux
...which says that I need to edit  **/etc/network/interfaces**  to create a bridge. If you read the comments on that same article, you will find that file is no longer being used and has been replaced with **/etc/netplan/***

My current  **.yaml**  file in  **/etc/netplan**  looks like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

My network interfaces appear to be  **enp0s25** ,  **wlp4s0** ,  and **wwp0s20u4** .

How should I change my netplan configuration so that my virtual machines on KVM can have an internet connection?

Comment: *This is not a server, so I do not need (or want) to make a remote connection possible. I only need to access them on the laptop they are hosted on.

Comment: see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html.en-CA#bridging).

Comment: You have to decide between using NetworkManager or Netplan. NetworkManager is GUI based. Netplan is cli based. If this is not a server, I'd recommend staying with NetworkManager (which is what your current /etc/netplan/*.yaml file is set for). Then just follow the instructions in the article link that you reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the default **yaml** file in **/etc/netplan** as follows:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      dhcp4: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: yes
      interfaces:
        - enp0s25
```